# TalkBack: Handling TalkBack spoken speed

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am using talkback as an accessibility service where we have requirements for controlling the speed of spoken text. I searched on different SO post to check for different options available to control the speed but I haven`t found any success.

Is there a way to control this programmatically?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with talkback, which leaves the speed up to the end-user (and I believe this is as it should be). 

If you access the speech synth directly (not through talkback) you would have the control you seek, but at the expense of the accessibility features that talkback offers. What is the use case?

Comment: @brennanyoung Use case is that some of the users want to playback at 1.5 x speed while others want to playback at normal speed using talkback services.

Comment: I think this is usually available via the user settings for talkback. Huawei does it like this https://www.techbone.net/huawei/user-manual/talkback-speech-rate

Comment: That`s the issue. We want this to be handled through Storm keypad which contains keys for increasing/decreasing the speech rate. I want to handle this through programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Let the user decide via the system level settings Accessibility->Talkback->More Settings->Text to-Speech settings->Speech Rate.

[image: Screenshot of Talkback Text-to-Speech settings showing]